# How to make API with required and optional parameters | PHP

Tags: php, api, parameter-passing, magento2, optional-parameters

Suppose there is a custom API to get giftcode.

The API has **Referance** and **Amount** as *requird parameters* whereas **Activated** and **Quantity** as *optional parameters*

If URL is:

http://ruteurl/rest/V1/giftcode/request?reference=XYZ&amount=50

It should run assuming Activated and Quantity to be 1 by default

If URL is:

http://ruteurl/rest/V1/giftcode/request?reference=XYZ&amount=50&activated=0&quantity=5

the values shoud be as provided in url and not the default ones.

How can we do this using php? (My platform is Magento 2)

Comment: Check if the GET-parameter is set, if not set a default value

Comment: @empiric can you share an example or link for setting GET-parameter, BTW I am using POST method to create API

Comment: You don't set GET-parameters, you set a variable with a value from the get parameter (or not): `$qty = isset($_GET['qunatitiy']) ? $_GET['qunatitiy'] : 1;`

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Null coalescing operator (??)](https://medium.com/sevensenders-techblog/modern-php-know-the-best-php-features-til-php-7-4-e3b2bf5916b2#a98a) to get a default value for a non-existing `key-value` in an array. For example:

```
$quantity = $_GET['quantity'] ?? 1;
$activated = $_GET['activated'] ?? 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This validation can be done in the server side. Make it as a PHP utility.

```
function validate_query_params($query_params)
{
    foreach($query_params as $key => &$value)
    {
        // Check for mandator params 
        // If any mandatory params missing, echo/print response with error 

        // else proceed with optional params. Use default values if missing

    }
}
```

Query params available in $_GET.